# does not support HTML5 Canvas element?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

The following code creates a Canvas element in an HTML page,
I Have Use this code but Error is shown bellow

```
<canvas id="exmpl" width="300" height="300">
This is Canvas Element..
</canvas>
```

Using JavaScript, I have draw on the canvas:

```
var exmpl= document.getElementById('exmpl');
var context = example.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
```

This code draws a red rectangle on the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is perfect always use higher level version if you use canvas tag.

```
var exmpl= document.getElementById('exmpl');
var context = example.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'higher version'?